# WCF Net.Tcp transport UserName

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-security, nettcpbinding

I want to only transport UserName maybe like this.
Od client sending:

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "name";
```

On server service consuming:

```
OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.PrimaryIdentity.Name;
```

But its needed some kind of security mode for transport or message. I will not use any of them for securing, only transporting name. I thing that all of security modes is sources or time consuming (more connections for one request).

Exists any possibility how to transport it with good efficiency or performance?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

try using 
 [ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel=ProtectionLevel.None)]